# Webhook - не исполняется npm

Tags: php, node.js, git, развертывание, npm

Пытаюсь организовать деплой из репозитория с последующей раскаткой, но любые команды связанные ничего не позвращают, работает только `git pull`.

По идее, `exec()` возвращает все, что было выведено в результате выполнения команды.

Тестирую команду напрямую из терминала - лог пишется, команда выполняется. Пытаюсь выполнить команду с помощью хука - возвращает *ничего*.

Что может быть не так? Может быть нужно делать что-то со стороны сервера?

Код тестового хука:

```
exec("cd /home/user/.local/bin/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64/bin/ && npm -v", $output);

foreach($output as $value) {
    echo $value . '; ';
}
```

Соответственно вместо версии npm, получаю ничего в теле.

Comment: Третьим параметром exec можно поймать статус завершения работы программы. Возможно, не хватает прав на выполнение. Возможно, нужно указать полный путь до npm

Comment: Полный путь указывал - тоже самое. Третьим параметром ловил, но смысла от этого не прибавилось, тк выполняется только `pull`, остальное опускается. Как я понял - проблема все таки в правах?

Comment: Скрипт от какого имени выполняется?

Comment: От обычного пользователя.